# A fieldtype with adjustable number of rows & the ability to add or remove columns per row?

Tags: matrix, fieldtype, dynamic

A client would like to be able to ‘build’ each detail page for their portfolio. The breakdown would be something like this:

Each row can have a combination of either a video block (embed), a text block or a photo block.

The elements themselves can be either full width, half width or quarter width, and so a row can accomodate from one to four elements depending.

There can be however many rows.

As a newcomer to expression engine, I’d love to get anyone’s thoughts on how best to execute on this using EE.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Is this about display on the front-end, or data entry on the back-end, Kenyabob?  Matrix may be part of the solution here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you'd want to look closely at [Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) or [Content Elements](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/content-elements) for this purpose, depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: Content elements seems like a better match! Matrix I think would make me define the content in each column, while I need to choose which content type each block will be as I go. I will look into content elements!